# Foreach with a multidimensional array - Laravel Blade

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, laravel-8

I am working on an air ticket reservation system project at laravel 8. When I call API I get a multidimensional array in return. Here is the array. I need to show 'ResultID', 'BaseFare','Tax' under the 'Fares' array

```
array:3 [▼
"SearchId" => "fca84241-dd9b-4cf2-bd6f-2f221dcc2b91"
"Results" => array:8 [▼
0 => array:14 [▼
  "ResultID" => "f0a54871-d728-424a-8e97-94e22308ac44"
  "IsRefundable" => true
  "Fares" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:9 [▼
      "BaseFare" => 2775.0
      "Tax" => 725.0
      "Currency" => "BDT"
      "OtherCharges" => 0.0
      "Discount" => 0.0
      "AgentMarkUp" => 0.0
      "PaxType" => "Adult"
      "PassengerCount" => 1
      "ServiceFee" => 0.0
    ]
  ]
  "Discount" => 0.0
  "Validatingcarrier" => "BG"
  "LastTicketDate" => "2022-05-30T00:00:00"
  "segments" => array:1 [▶]
  "TotalFare" => 3500.0
  "TotalFareWithAgentMarkup" => 3500.0
  "Currency" => "BDT"
  "Availabilty" => 1
  "FareType" => "InstantTicketing"
  "isMiniRulesAvailable" => false
  "HoldAllowed" => false
]
1 => array:14 [▶]
2 => array:14 [▶]
3 => array:14 [▶]
4 => array:14 [▶]
5 => array:14 [▶]
6 => array:14 [▶]
7 => array:14 [▶]
]
"Error" => null
]
```

This is my controller function if it is useful in any case.

```
       $response = $client->post($url,
               ['form_params' => $travel_data]
       );

       $response = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

       $data['flight']= $response;
       $data['app']= App_setting::find(1);
       return view('agent.flights.search_results',$data);
```

Below is my code block in blade.php but it gives me the error, I tried several methods but was failed to create the loop.

```
@foreach ($flight as $key => $teamArray)
         @foreach($teamArray as $team_Array)
               @php
                      echo "<pre>";
                      print_r($teamArray['Fares'][0]['BaseFare']);
               @endphp
                   
         @endforeach

   @endforeach
```

Comment: Please share the error

Comment: show the error plus I guess the foreach does not satisfy what you need to fetch

Answer (score 0):

You are using the variable `teamArray` instead of `team_Array` in the inner foreach, but you can omit the second foreach.

To get the value of * SearchId* and the values of *BaseFare* and *Tax*:

```
$flight = [
    [
        "SearchId" => "fca84241-dd9b-4cf2-bd6f-2f221dcc2b91",
        "Results" => [
            0 => [
                "ResultID" => "f0a54871-d728-424a-8e97-94e22308ac44",
                "IsRefundable" => true,
                "Fares" => [
                    0 => [
                        "BaseFare" => 2775.0,
                        "Tax" => 725.0,
                        "Currency" => "BDT"
                    ]
                ],
                "Discount" => 0.0,
                "Validatingcarrier" => "BG"
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

foreach ($flight as $key => $teamArray) {
    echo $teamArray["SearchId"] . PHP_EOL;
    foreach($teamArray["Results"] as $result) {
        echo ($result["Fares"][0]["BaseFare"]) . PHP_EOL;
        echo ($result["Fares"][0]["Tax"]) . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output

```
fca84241-dd9b-4cf2-bd6f-2f221dcc2b91
2775
725
```

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/a04IR)

Comment: ErrorException
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /home/softcombd/public_html/air_ticket/resources/views/agent/flights/search_results.blade.php)

Comment: @NoorMohammadBabu Which ones of the `foreach` is giving this error? Is `teamArray` an array?

Comment: 2nd foreach giving this error.   @foreach ($teamArray as $team_Array)

Comment: @NoorMohammadBabu Then you can `var_dump($teamArray);` and see what it gives you

Comment: @NoorMohammadBabu What if you omit that foreach and use `foreach ($flight as $key => $teamArray) {
    echo $teamArray["ResultID"] . PHP_EOL;
    echo ($teamArray["Fares"][0]["BaseFare"]) . PHP_EOL;
    echo ($teamArray["Fares"][0]["Tax"]) . PHP_EOL;
}`

Comment: How to convert  this array type Array
([0] => Array (  [ResultID] => 0e54aded-d86b-4099-a264-cbf28deacb07  [Fares] => Array
            ( [0] => Array ( [BaseFare] => 4175
                        [Tax] => 725
                        [Currency] => BDT
     --------------  to   ---------------$flight1 = [
                        [ "ResultID" => "0e54aded-d86b-4099-a264-cbf28deacb07", "Fares" => [
                                [ "BaseFare" => 4175, "Tax" => 725 ] ] ]
                    ];

Comment: 1st one is my array and 2nd one is your array. your array working fine. how to convert this

Comment: @NoorMohammadBabu Can you do a `var_export($flight)` of your source array and update the question with that one?

Comment: @ The fourth bird-  update source array please check

Comment: @NoorMohammadBabu Like this? https://3v4l.org/a04IR

Comment: @ The fourth bird- its working thanks :)